# failed prepared statement and img file upload

Tags: php, html, image, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am attempting to create my first prepared statement and I could really use some help to see what I'm doing wrong. I had most of my query working properly before doing this, but everyone told me I should do it this way to prevent SQL Injection.

I'm trying to send product info to my database. Included in this data, I am trying to send an img file and have it moved into my db. Before attempting this prepared statement I was doing a simple mysqli insert statement and the only part of my query that did not work was getting the file name of the img to show up in my database as the actual file name. The way it was uploading was as "array" or "1". I changed things around to try to make it work with the procedure statement the best I could.

I'm not too sure if my attempt to upload the img file is correct in this prepared statement or not. The reason being is none of this is even being sent to my data base now. I am not getting any errors with my database connection.

I start this off with validation. I do not have any validation for the img file yet. I will add that later once I can get this to actually send.

I then process the form info. I'm not sure if my $file variable is structured right for sending the file name to the db as I'm getting an error.

I get this error with the php error info on.. Notice: Undefined index: img in /home4/pfarley1/public_html/addproduct.php on line 90

```
//Create
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if($validation->passed()) {
    if(isset($_POST['create'])){ 
        $product_id = trim( $_POST['product_id'] );
        $name = trim( $_POST['name'] );
        $price = trim( $_POST['price'] );
        $saleprice = trim( $_POST['saleprice'] );
        $final_price = trim( $_POST['final_price'] );
        $shippingprice = trim( $_POST['shippingprice'] );
        $category = trim( $_POST['category'] );
        $item_details = trim( $_POST['item_details'] );
        $item_details2 = trim( $_POST['item_details2'] );
        $description = trim( $_POST['description'] );
        $viewproduct_type = trim( $_POST['viewproduct_type'] );
        $date = ( $_POST['date_created'] );
 //line 90 $file = ($_POST ['img'] [move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"productpics/". $_FILES['file']['name'])] );

    //Connection
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bfb");
    /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }



    /* create a prepared statement */
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO products ('product_id', 'name', 'price', 'saleprice', 'final_price', 'shippingprice', 'category', item_details', 'item_details2', 'description', 'viewproduct_type', 'date', 'img') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {


        /* bind parameters for markers */
        $stmt->bind_param('isiiiisssssis', $product_id, $name, $price, $saleprice, $final_price, $shippingprice, $category, $item_details, $item_details2, $description, $viewproduct_type, $date, $file);

        /* execute query */
        $stmt->execute();


    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
  }
 }
 }   
?>
```

The form

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="product_id">Product ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="product_id" class="smallinputbar" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="name">Product Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="price">Product Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="price" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="saleprice">Sale Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="saleprice">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="final_price">Final Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="final_price" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="shippingprice">Shipping Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="shippingprice" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="category" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="item_details">Item Details</label>
        <input type="message" class="messageinput" name="item_details" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="item_details2">Item Details 2</label>
        <input type="message" class="messageinput" name="item_details2">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <input type="message" class="messageinput" name="description" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="viewproduct_type">View Product Type</label>
        <select class="optionbar" name="viewproduct_type">
            <option name="notSelected">Not Selected</option>
            <option name="viewproduct_type" value="a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id">Standard</option>
            <option name="viewproduct_type" value="Option">Option</option>
        </select>
    </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
        <label for="button">

        <input type="submit" id="button" name="create" value="Create New Product">
        </label>

    <span class="floatright">
        <input type="file" name="file" class="inputbarfile">
        <input type="submit" name="create" id="signinButton" value="Upload">
    </span>
```

I followed examples from the php manual and youtube, but none are really like what I am doing, especially with adding in the img file upload.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong with my prepared statement or the way I am trying to upload the img file? I've been stuck in the img file upload for a long time and have tried a million different ways.

Comment: Your form doesn't contain a field called `img`. What is that `$_POST['img']` supposed to be? The file isn't in the `$_POST`, it's in `$_FILES`.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to structure that. I read that when you are uploading a file, you must name it file. The spot it is going into the database is called img. How can I structure it so it will go into my img row in my db?

Comment: Ok, when you send files, you have `<input type="file" name="file" />`. The `name` attribute is the index name in which the value will be in PHP. When you send files, it's contained in `$_FILES` superglobal variable. To access the file from your form, you use `$_FILES['name_in_the_form_field']`. In your case, it would be `$_FILES['file']`.

Comment: So since I have $_FILES['file'] already in my variable for file. Would I just have to change the file name in the form to say img? 'code'<input type="file" name="file" class="inputbarfile">'code'